# How do I allow images in a textbox | ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tinymce

I am developing an ASP.NET Core application & I need a control as described below:

Is there an existing control or a way to allow users to insert images in a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to simply insert an image into a textbox. WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE give the appearance that this happening by rendering a HTML area with an `img` tag pointing to an image file at some location. In the end, what's submitted is this backing HTML, not the image itself.

For something like an image that already exists at some publicly-accessible location online, nothing more is required. However, if you're talking about allowing a user to embed an image that exists only on their local filesystem, that requires additional machinery. Again, WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE often include something along the lines of a "file browser" or "upload" control that handles this type of thing. When the user picks an image from their computer, the control uploads that image to some location on the server and then, again, adds a simple `img` tag pointing to the now online location of that image. This has to be configured, though. There's usually server-side scripts that must be installed on the server and you have to somehow tell it both where to store the uploaded images and how to address them from a publicly-accessible URL. This is likely what you're missing with TinyMCE. However, setting all that up is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. Consult the documentation for your library of choice.